# I can't install Bootstrap to Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to install bootstrap to my symfony2 project.
I basically followed steps from this: http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started

However, when I try to run my server using: `php app\console server:run`
I got this error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   the file "filters/assets.xml" does not exist (in: C:..\ProjectName\vendor\symfony\assetic-bundle\Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\DependencyInjection/..Resources/config).

I already go to that folder and can't found that assets.xml file.

I'm pretty sure that there's something went wrong with my config.yml file. Here is the config of assetic

> assetic:
>     java: /usr/bin/java
>     filters:
>       cssembed:
>         jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/cssembed-0.4.5.jar
>       yui_js:
>         jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar
>       lessphp:
>         file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
>         apply_to: ".less$"
>     assets:
>       jquery_js:
>           inputs:
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/app/Resources/public/js/vendor/jquery.js'
>           filters: [?yui_js]
>       bootstrap_js:
>           inputs:
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-button.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js'
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-affix.js'
>           filters: [?yui_js]
>       bootstrap_less:
>           inputs:
>               - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'
>           filters: [lessphp,cssembed]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows i suggest right?

Comment: Yes, Windows. Could you take a look at my config.yml for assetic. I have no idea

Comment: please see my answer. and please fix your config.yml in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see you have configured **lessphp** as one of your assetic filters and not less ( as you are on windows and have not configured less properly ). Change config.yml this to actually use lessphp instead of the less command

```
# app/config/config.yml

assetic:
    # ...
    assets:
        bootstrap_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/responsive.less
            filters:
                - lessphp             # change this form less to lessphp
```

Furthermore there might be something wrong with your paths , looking at the error:

```
C:..\ProjectName\vendor\symfony\asseticbundle\Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\DependencyInjection/..Resources/config
```

... should be a valid path like ...

```
C:\ProjectName\vendor\symfony\assetic-bundle\Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config
```

... for symfony/php to actually be able find filters/assets.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this and found this bundle more helpful than trying to install it outright ...

https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle

It's documentation can be a little fuzzy, but overall it worked fairly well. I used it with SASS, but it has LESS and plain CSS options as well.